# Javascript return var

Tags: javascript, var

The code below is returning `gracz.N0P` but I want it to return 1, 3, 0 etc.
I don't want to use `if()` and `switch()`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var gracz = {
    N0P: 1,
    N1P: 3,
    N2P: 0,
    (...)
}
function showType(nr)
{
    return "gracz.N" + nr + "P";
}
```

Comment: Try `return gracz["N" + nr + "P"];`

Comment: Thanks `return gracz["N" + nr + "P"];` working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a string, return the object property. Try this:

```
function showType(nr){
    return gracz['N' + nr + 'P'];
}
```

You can easily access properties dynamically by using the “bracket notation”.